# Which dotnet docker image should I use for AKS?

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-aks

[Official .NET Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-sdk/) images support three Linux distors:

- Debian - `3.1.201-buster`
- Alpine - `3.1.201-alpine`
- Ubuntu - `3.1.201-bionic`

I didn't find much in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/net-core-net-framework-containers/net-container-os-targets):

[image: Operating systems to target depending on versions of the .NET framework]

Which and why should prefer one over another? Since AKS nodes are Ubuntu based they all work. So which should I select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are all base don the same architecture, I would say that the deciding factor should be

1) which image is the smaller (or not as big)

2) which comes with built in binaries that are useful to your need. (e.g. the alpine base normally handles DNS lookup differently when using nslookup)
e.g : https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/476

In the end, it is up to you, what is important, you pick one that you are comfortable with and one with you trust more with respect to CVE and security updates to be available the fastest.